# NSViewController disable resize when presented as Sheet?

Tags: macos, nsviewcontroller

So I am presenting an NSViewController **as a sheet** of a window that has resize disabled.

The view controller that is presented as a sheet *can still be resized*.

How do I disable resizing of a NSViewController?

Comment: If you un-tick the "resize" checkbox in the interface editor you won't be able to resize the window. How do you resize the view?

Comment: Yes the window I can't resize but if I presentViewControllerAsSheet then I can resize that view which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Swift 4:**

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
   // any additional code
   view.window!.styleMask.remove(.resizable)
}
```

By the way you can do this without writing code, here is how:

- Drag a Window Controller element to the Storyboard from the Object
  Library.
- Connect the Window Controller to the specific View Controller which you want to disable resize.
- On the Window Controller's Attributes uncheck Resize option.

[image: disable resize window xcode]

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for views presented as `sheets`, as indicated in the text of the question.

Comment: This does NOT work for a view presented by `presentAsSheet()`.

Comment: It works fine for me on a controller presented as a sheet. Just make sure to put the code in `viewDidAppear`, not `viewDidLoad`. `view.window` is `nil` in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 11):

After some more trying I found out this did the trick in viewDidLoad:

```
self.preferredContentSize = NSMakeSize(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: worked for me if you ovverride (void)updateViewConstraints method

Comment: may be simply -  `preferredContentSize = view.frame.size`

Answer (score 1):

If you add these methods, the issue will be fixed.

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_10) {

    [super updateViewConstraints];

}

- (void)viewWillLayout NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_10) {

    self.preferredContentSize = NSMakeSize(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

}
```